# Dropzone.js uploading Base64 strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I'm using a javascript plugin Dropzone.js to help make my uploading seems seamless to the user. It's also what my company wants to use so I have no choice in the matter!

I'm running into an issue though where the image or document needs to be converted into Base64 to save to the database. Is there a simple way to do so? I have tried an `ondrop` method, but I failed miserably.

My function that calls the dropzone

```
$("#attachments").dropzone({
    maxFiles: 2000,
    url: baseUrl + 'rest/insert',
    addedfile: function(file) {
      var base64 = ''
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(event) {
        base64 = event.target.result;
        console.log(base64)
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
     },
    success: function(file, response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: can your serverside do the encoding?

Comment: @DanielA.White, No I need to do it on the front end to pass to the backend.

Comment: There are libraries you can use on the frontend to encode if your server won't.

Comment: @Phix I cannot use a different library. I am trying to use this plugin to upload the images.

Answer (score 3):

In `addedfile()` you will get the *base64* of the file. Append the recorded *base64* to formData in `sending()` callback.

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var base64 = '';
$("#attachments").dropzone({
    url: "/",
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    maxFiles: 2000,
    sending: function(file, xhr, formData){
        formData.append("base64", base64);
    },
    addedfile: function(file) {
        var _this=this,
            reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(event) {
            base64 = event.target.result;
            _this.processQueue()
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    },
    success: function(file, response) {
        console.log('success:', response);
    }

});
```

Comment: I just added this before my success function and now the image no longer appears in the window when it's dragged in. I am also receiving the same 'unsupported media type' message indicating that it didn't convert.

Comment: did you set parameter(s) to "acceptedFiles" attributes?  give it some values like, "acceptedFiles : image/*,application/pdf" [ assuming that you are supporting all kind of images and pdf files ]

Comment: I don't have an acceptedFiles param because this needs to accept everything, including js files or word docs. Does this need an acceptFiles field in order to work?

Comment: I just attempted to put in an acceptedFiles for testing and it didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Looking further it seems that the image actually uploads before this function actually loads. I will update my question to add this function.

Comment: The request payload is still the details of the file and not the actual base64.

------WebKitFormBoundaryTy8Cx2NGeIyTmWbM
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="download.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryTy8Cx2NGeIyTmWbM--

Comment: can you please share more code? that would help. or I have created one plunker here https://plnkr.co/edit/qIayTCjGb7qXbwtVJBSx?p=preview, which is kind of mimic of your code signature. keep browser console open and drop some file you wish over there. you would notice base64 will get logged on the console. NOTE: image won't be visible as you need to make a change in dropzone URL.

Comment: I do not have any other code than what I shared. I see the console happening, but when I'm looking at the request payload within the console and not seeing the base64, but rather what I pasted above. That's what is actually being sent to the backend. What change do I need to make in the dropzone url to make the image show up when it's dragged in?

Comment: updated the answer, please check. now, you would able to see the base64 in the request payload

Comment: I'm playing with this and trying to get the backend to accept it. However, the backend won't accept anything except for an object. Like a regular ajax call/ I tried placing an object within the formData.append, but was unsuccessful. Is there anyway to make this into an object instead of the browser based code?

Answer (score 0):

Lil late to answer but sharing how I solved it.
using `accept` instead of `addedfile`

```
myDropZone = new Dropzone("div#dropZoneContainer", {
    url: "/",
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    maxFiles: 1,
    accept: function (file) {
        reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (event) {
            imageData = event.target.result;
            console.log(imageData);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    },
});
```